# Create a nice "About" XML Layout using rich text?

Tags: android

I intend to make a good "**About**" section in my application that gives the user some basic information about the developer and the app itself. 
I didn't find a **rich** `EditText` among the `Widgets`.

I have searched for other questions similar to mine here and I found something like using a `WebView` or a `TextView` and giving them `HTML` attributes in the code.

Is there any nice and professional way to do my **About** XML Layout?

Comment: You can use tabs. It looks plain and attractive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use multiple TextViews and position them accordingly.

Comment: I prefer using multiple `TextView`s as you said because I can align a specific word at the bottom of the Layout, unlike the `WebView`, which it was a bit confusing.

Comment: Glad you got it working, but multiple `TextView`'s makes updating the text hard, since you usually have to change multiple resources. The `WebView` just displays regular HTML, so you have to edit a single file. If you are not comfortable with HTML, or have mostly static text, a regular layout should also do fine.

Answer (score 1):

If you need high control and rich text, use a `WebView` and load a static HTML file. You can achieve a lot with Spans (bold, itallick, links, etc.) in a simple TextView as well but it is generally more work.